# Put translated resx files in a different folder in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, globalization, resx

I've got a solution with 14 translations and 12 files and the "Resources" folder is getting a bit out of hand. Is there a way to put the translated files into a different folder so I can access the master English ones more easily?

I've noticed that you can change the namespace the designer file is generated in by setting the Custom Tool Namespace, but I haven't figured out how to pick up translations from a different folder. I toyed with the idea of using links to make a "shortcuts" folder and a "real" folder but you can't link to a file within the project structure and you can't link to the same file twice outside of the project structure. I thought about changing the namespace that the ResourceManager used based on the language but that would break the fallback behavior.

Is there any way to manage this so it isn't a giant list of files in Solution Explorer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you want to place all the translated .resx files in a `Translations` folder, like this (note I have left the *default* and *en* versions in the root folder):

[image]

Then all you need to do is edit the MSBuild project file (from Visual Studio, right-click on the project node, 'Unload project', then 'Edit xxx.csproj'), and reconfigure each Resx file in this folder like this:

before:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resource1.en.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Translations\Resource1.fr.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resource1.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resource1.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
```

after:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resource1.en.resx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Translations\Resource1.fr.resx">
      <ManifestResourceName>$(TargetName).%(Filename)</ManifestResourceName> <!-- add this for all .resx files in a custom folder -->
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resource1.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resource1.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
```

What it does is instruct underlying MSBuild tasks to use the manifest name you specificy instead of generating one automatically. The automatically generated one always uses the folder layout where the RESX resides in which is not what we want.

After compilation, the final satellite `ConsoleApplication1.resources.dll` file will be placed in the `fr` folder as usual, but its content will be the same as if the resx file was placed in the root folder.

Comment: Although an extremely useful titbit of info, I'm not sure it quite addresses the OP's original problem. I think his issue is with clutter in the resources folder, not the output bin directory.  I may be  mistaken though. +1 for the tip from me.

Comment: This does not change the output bin directory layout nor content, just how the files are organized in the Visual Studio project, which corresponds to the question title, from what I understand.

Comment: So it does. I was mistaken!

Comment: This looks quite handy! If you were originally keeping the resources in the Resources folder, you'd make it `<ManifestResourceName>$(TargetName).Resources.%(Filename)</ManifestResourceName>` I think I might stick with my answer because I don't have to do any extra work when adding translations or resource files. Though I'm sure you could write a script to do it for you..

Comment: Oh, even better, you can just say `<EmbeddedResource Include="Translations\*.resx">` and it will grab all of them!

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this could be to write a custom resource provider. Rick Strahl wrote one to serve resources from a database rather than RESX files. The class he inherits from is System.Resources.ResourceManager in mscorlib. Here is his implementation.

https://github.com/RickStrahl/Westwind.Globalization/blob/master/Westwind.Globalization/DbResourceManager/DbResourceManager.cs

Here is a link to the article, and he provides the code.

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Mar/31/Updated-ASPNET-Database-Resource-Provider

I realise you dont want to store the resources from a DB, but the principle should apply

Comment: Interesting... but I have found no way to have VS use my custom ResourceManager in its generated files. It looks like you can't do that yet? https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3873228-provide-a-resourcemanager-abstraction-mechanism .

Answer (score 1):

The combination of *Simon Mourier* and *RandomEngy* answers help me get it working with Visual Studio 2022.
I inserted the following text right before the first **EmbeddedResource** tag in the *.csproj file.

```
<EmbeddedResource Update="Translations\*.resx">
    <ManifestResourceName>$(TargetName).%(Filename)</ManifestResourceName>
    <!-- add this for all .resx files in a custom folder -->
</EmbeddedResource>
```

That will pull in all the resx files in the **Translations** folder.
I had to use "**Update**" instead of using "**Include**". Every time I used include, I got a build error.