# WPF: Localization using x:Uid and resx

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to switch application language at application runtime by using x:Uid and resx.
I have already set up the cultureinfo to the language I want in **App.cs**.

```cs
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("zh-CN");

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

and I have some string under `/Language/zh-CN/Resources.resx` file.

```
Control_ConnectButton.Content 连接
Control_TestButton.Content 测试
```

Button xaml

```
<Button x:Name="ConnectButton" x:Uid="Control_ConnectButton" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Click="ConnectButton_Click" Margin="28,0,0,0" MinWidth="70" />
<Button x:Name="TestButton" x:Uid="Control_TestButton" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Click="TestButton_Click" Margin="28,0,0,0" MinWidth="70" />
```

However when I start the application, the text on the button is empty.
[image]

What did I do wrong?

I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: There is no magic mechanism matching `x:Uid` to strings in a resx file. You could use `{x:Static res:Resources.Control_ConnectButton}` if you let VisualStudio create a Resources.Designer.cs and specify the access to be "public". See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072839/how-to-localize-wpf-application-with-resx-files-in-subdirectories

Comment: Thank you very much! It work just as intended.